# Advantages of a checkAndCreateDatabase method over direct mainBundle reference

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm learning Objective-C, so please, be nice.   :-)

While learning how to connect Objective-C and a SQLite db, I found some authors suggesting to use this method (or a very similar one) before starting querying the db:

```
-(void) checkAndCreateDatabase{

    BOOL success;

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    if(success) return;

    NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];

    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePath error:nil];

    [fileManager release];
}
```

Which is the main advantage of using this code over using `NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDb" ofType:@"sqlite"]` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS you can not write to the app bundle so the database is usually copied to the apps sandbox area.

The following code is fine to get the path to your database in the app  bundle:

```
NSString *dbPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"myDb" ofType:@"sqlite"];
```

The document directory path can be found with this code:

```
NSArray  *documentDirList = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentDir  = [documentDirList objectAtIndex:0];
```

There are several other directories you can search for, lookup the enumeration: `NSSearchPathDirectory`.

Comment: But, when I drag the file to my XCode project, where am I placing it? If I'm placing it in the mainBundle, I don't understand why I must check for its presence, since I'm sure I added it to my project. What am I missing?

Comment: The idea is to check the location it will be copied to in order to copy it only once. `databasePath` is the location the database is being copied to.

Comment: I understand this. What I can't understand is why use this code if I manually place the db in the mainBundle.

Comment: If the database tries to write to the database and the database is in the app bundle the write will fail. Leaving it in the app bundle may be OK if the database is only read but even reading _may_ try to update the database meta data.

Comment: OK! This is the answer I was looking for!   :-)